# Groupby replace val column for entire group with 1 if there negative value in group pandas

Tags: pandas

**Groupby replace val column for entire group with 1 if there negative value in group pandas**

```
lst = [['AAA',2019,15],['BBB',2019,16],['BBB',2020,22],['AAA',2020,-20],['CCC',2019,11],['AAA',2021,10]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst,columns = ['name','year','val'])
```

Output

```
name year val
AAA  2019 1
AAA  2020 1
AAA  2021 1
BBB  2019 16
BBB  2020 22
CCC  2019 11
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `name` values by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with filtered `name`s if less value like `0` and pass to [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for set `1`:

```
df.loc[df['name'].isin(df.loc[df['val'].lt(0), 'name']), 'val'] = 1

df = df.sort_values('name', ignore_index=True)
print (df)
  name  year  val
0  AAA  2019    1
1  AAA  2020    1
2  AAA  2021    1
3  BBB  2019   16
4  BBB  2020   22
5  CCC  2019   11
```

Or id performance is not important use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html):

```
df.loc[df['val'].lt(0).groupby(df['name']).transform('any'), 'val'] = 1

df = df.sort_values('name', ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: what is .lt func?

Comment: @SukantaBiswas - it is less function - [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html)